# Get video played details using mplayer

Tags: video, mplayer, logs

I am working on a project which gets a video URL from the server and then plays it. Once the video is completed it asks for another link from the server and plays it after receiving the URL.

I am playing the video using mplayer. My new requirement is, my device should ask for a new link when the video has been played at 50%.

How can I get the played status of the video?

The logs I get while playing the video is...

```
fa@FriendlyELEC:~/Desktop/MediaFiles$ mplayer video.mp4 
MPlayer2 2.0-728-g2c378c7-4+b1 (C) 2000-2012 MPlayer Team
Cannot open file '/home/fa/.mplayer/input.conf': No such file or directory
Failed to open /home/fa/.mplayer/input.conf.
Cannot open file '/etc/mplayer/input.conf': No such file or directory
Failed to open /etc/mplayer/input.conf.

Playing video.mp4.
Detected file format: QuickTime / MOV (libavformat)
[lavf] stream 0: video (h264), -vid 0
Clip info:
 major_brand: dash
 minor_version: 0
 compatible_brands: iso6avc1mp41
 creation_time: 2016-01-27 09:00:27
Load subtitles in .
[vdpau] Error when calling vdp_device_create_x11: 25
[VO_XV] It seems there is no Xvideo support for your video card available.
[VO_XV] Run 'xvinfo' to verify its Xv support and read
[VO_XV] DOCS/HTML/en/video.html#xv!
[VO_XV] See 'mplayer -vo help' for other (non-xv) video out drivers.
[VO_XV] Try -vo x11.
[ass] auto-open
Selected video codec: H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10 [libavcodec]
Audio: no sound
Starting playback...
VIDEO:  1920x1080  23.976 fps  1902.3 kbps (237.8 kB/s)
VO: [x11] 1920x1080 => 1920x1080 Planar YV12 
[swscaler @ 0xb5d30980]No accelerated colorspace conversion found from yuv420p to bgra.
[swscaler @ 0xb5d30980]using unscaled yuv420p -> bgra special converter
Colorspace details not fully supported by selected vo.
V:  54.0   0/  0  7% 163%  0.0% 0 0
```

I want to get the status of **V:**

```
V:  54.0   0/  0  7% 163%  0.0% 0 0
```